# C send emojis with sendmessage()

Tags: c, winapi

I want send emojis to a browser like chrome or Microsoft edge with the `sendmessage()` function.
When i defined a string with the emojis and write it with `fputs()` to a .txt file the output is the expected in format of `❤❤ ++` .

The string: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "\U00002764\U00002764 ++ \U0001F618\U0001F618");`
The buffer array use the `char` datatype.

With the `sendmessage()` function i do not get the expected output. Trying to send a maximizewindow command works. Following is my codesnipped i use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_UNICHAR, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)buffer[i]);
}
```

I also tryed `PostMessage()` and `PostMessageW()`.

Comment: You're not sending Unicode characters, you're sending individual bytes, converted to an `LPARAM`. The first message you send will be `0x0000000000000000` (the byte `0x00` converted to a 64-bit integer type). The second will be the same, the third will be the byte `0x27`, and so on...

Comment: what can i do to send the emoji correct?

Comment:  is `3d d8 18 de` in memory, `TEXT("\xd83d\xde18")` in `wchar_t`. Send `0xde18d83d` as the `WPARAM` in little endian computers if the program supports `WM_UNICHAR`.

Comment: I try `PostMessage(hwnd, WM_UNICHAR, (WPARAM)0xde18d83d, 0);` but nothing happens. My compiler is Mingw32. When im using WM_CHAR an '=' will printed.

Comment: This isn't how to automate browsers. There are countless posts on this topic. If you'd searched you'd see thousands of answers saying that you can't fake input with PostMessage/SendMessage etc. Browsers all have automation interfaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is no automation purpose.. I want to add emojis in Webwhatsapp with hotkeys on special persons and not to all

Comment: That's precisely what automation does though. I mean, you can carry on sending messages, but you should be aware that it won't work.

Comment: I developed an APP in Autoit that does exactly do what i descriped but i want it in C. As far i know, Autoit uses the winapi. So it must work but how is the question

Comment: As far as the question is concerned, `SendMessage` `UNICODE_NOCHAR` to get whether that application supports `WM_UNICHAR` before sending Unicode characters as [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar#parameters) says. And [These functions just forward messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/sendmessage--postmessage--and-related-functions).

Comment: Your logic about autoit is wrong. Autoit isn't using SendMessage.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT what can i do when my system not support wm_unichar? I also tried Visual Studio with `wmain()` function and `#define UNICODE` but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find any way to use `SendMessage()` with `WM_UNICHAR` after hours. But for me i found a good alternative solution with `SendInput()`. These function supports UTF32 characters and works in every window i tested. Following i will post my code to help others.

```
short si_ret;
INPUT pInputs;
pInputs.type        =   INPUT_KEYBOARD;
pInputs.ki.wVk      =   0; //Use here normal characters when dwFlags zero, otherwise on unicode set wVk to zero
pInputs.ki.wScan    =   (WORD)0; //Use L'❤' to send UTF-32 characters or the matching value (see WEB or wprintf)
pInputs.ki.dwFlags  =   KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
wchar_t text[] = L"❤❤";
        
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < wcslen(text); x++)
{
    pInputs.ki.wScan    =   (WORD)text[x];
    if(!(si_ret = SendInput(1, &pInputs, sizeof(pInputs)))) { printf("SendInput do not work [%i]\r\n", GetLastError()); return 0; }
    else { printf("SendInput ok [%i]\r\n", si_ret); }
}
```